# How to decide constexpr to return a reference or not

Tags: c++, c++17, constexpr, auto, if-constexpr

If you have a function that `if constexpr ()` decides to do one thing or the other, how to return an lvalue in one case and an rvalue in the other case?

The following example does not compile in the first usage line, because the return type `auto` is no reference:

```
static int number = 15;

template<bool getref>
auto get_number(int sometemporary)
{
    if constexpr(getref)
    {
        return number; // we want to return a reference here
    }
    else
    {
        (...) // do some calculations with `sometemporary`
        return sometemporary;
    }
}

void use()
{
    int& ref = get_number<true>(1234);
    int noref = get_number<false>(1234);
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> how to return an lvalue in one case and an rvalue in the other case?

I suppose you can try with `decltype(auto)` and a couple of parentheses

```
template<bool getref>
decltype(auto) get_number() // "decltype(auto)" instead of "auto"
{
    if constexpr(getref)
    {
        return (number); // not "number" but "(number)"
    }
    else
    {
        return 123123; // just a random number as example
    }
}
```

Comment: @AartStuurman - mainly an intuition... I remember that the difference between `auto` and `decltype(auto)` is that `decltype(auto)` is more flexible and useful to obtain informations about references (or not). And the parentheses is because `decltype(number)` return `int` where `decltype((number))` return `int &`.

Comment: I never even knew about decltype(auto), and the parentheses to make an lvalue are also logical if you think about it. Weird stuff, thanks.

Answer (score 4):

`std::ref` seems to do the trick for me:

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

static int number = 15;

template<bool getref>
auto get_number()
{
    if constexpr(getref)
    {
        return std::ref(number); // we want to return a reference here
    }
    else
    {
        return 123123; // just a random number as example
    }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int& ref = get_number<true>();
    int noref = get_number<false>();

    std::cout << "Before ref " << ref << " and number " << number << std::endl;
    ref = argc;
    std::cout << "After ref " << ref << " and number " << number << std::endl;

    std::cout << "Before noref " << noref << " and number " << number << std::endl;
    noref = argc * 2;
    std::cout << "After noref " << noref << " and number " << number << std::endl;
}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##pVBha8IwEP2@X3E4GK1ORMcY2Cpsf2TE9FIz2qSkyRSGf33dJdF2m8wPLpTkevfu3r3Hm2Zact51QOdWKl65AiEXTnErtWLV@uZnRerWGmR1zIertcxKDlJZUK7eoIEVzB@zAWCxbipmMd9oXUGJNEDEfuas9onX2JikIfsRbn@kAK5Va3HfmCQ2pn1xgPlj0DqjaJliuSRYEiemGcxmsEPYMVqPyI4wRoFAg4ojbOntRx36CKsWL3PNFw/0BYY311o/lKlC1ycbWAu4Z6T99/jD4I13rWZSJT5gpuT3wLfMwHhMP@9nfih75zcnhwfXcmscrpM0@w4Dpc9wgpGkHtijg2VcOwt5DqMXFNQZSEY@4QOfB5J2EhYKx5iiMABVUQ0bRG6vJ/uD51lY6r6S5vLuUXrs1tftf3LPK4AxLC6r@Cfhoes@uahY2XZTKq34ZDJ/@gI)

As expected, changing `ref` changes `number` (and not `noref`), while changing `noref` changes nothing else.

Since the behavior is `constexpr` and templated, returning `std::ref` of `number` forces it to actually make a reference.

Comment: You may want to note that doing this "breaks" `auto& ref = get_number<true>();`.  http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/31de626e49387a49

Comment: @NathanOliver: Hmm... Good point. The caller would have to explicitly call `.get()` on the result to use `auto&`, or explicitly declare the variable `int&` without it. Not great. [max66's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55301861/364696), while rather more magical looking/less intuitive, does seem to work identically storing to both `auto&` and `int&`, so I'd probably recommend their solution (with a quick inline comment to explain the magic). Gave them an up-vote. :-)

Comment: I find your solution more intuitive, but max66's solution (sadly) has better results. :)